# No data returning back to view page after implementing pagedlist MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on displaying data based on the user logged in. In this application, I have added couple of contact information in database. Before, I was able to display all data. Now the thing is I have implemented PagedList in table and while returning data I am not able to return the data of the user who is logged in. All contacts have appeared. 
Here is my code.

```
public ActionResult Index(ContactModel contact, string sortOrder, string CurrentSort, int? page)
    {
        var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        contact.UserId = currentUserId;

        int pageSize = 5;
        int pageIndex = 1;
        pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;

        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

        sortOrder = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "ContactID" : sortOrder;

        IPagedList<ContactModel> cnt = null;
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "ContactID":
                if (sortOrder.Equals(CurrentSort))
                    cnt = db.Contact.OrderByDescending
                            (m => m.ContactID).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
                else
                    cnt = db.Contact.OrderBy
                            (m => m.ContactID).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
                break;

            case "Contact_Name":
                if (sortOrder.Equals(CurrentSort))
                    cnt = db.Contact.OrderByDescending
                            (m => m.Name).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
                else
                    cnt = db.Contact.OrderBy
                            (m => m.Name).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
                break;

            case "Email":
                if (sortOrder.Equals(CurrentSort))
                    cnt = db.Contact.OrderByDescending
                            (m => m.Email).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
                else
                    cnt = db.Contact.OrderBy
                            (m => m.Email).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
                break;

            case "Default":
                cnt = db.Contact.OrderBy
                        (m => m.ContactID).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
                break;
        }
        var contactData = db.Contact.Where(x => x.UserId == currentUserId);
        return View(cnt);

    }
```

How can I achieve the data of user who logged in with PagedList? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code  `cnt` is only ordered list but where clause is applied on`contactData`. You should apply where on `cnt` and the return `contactData`. Like as following

```
var contactData = cnt.Where(x => x.UserId == currentUserId);
return View(contactData);
```

This should solve your issue.